# VBA to do Vlookup in Excel sheet with Vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vba

I m new to Excel VBA. i need to do a vlookup in excel sheet with this vlookup formula:

```
=INT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,[sheet.xls]Sheet1!B:F,5,FALSE),0))
```

Could any one guide me to apply this vlookup using VBA

Answer (score 0):

Basic approach:

```
myRange.Formula = "=INT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,[sheet.xls]Sheet1!B:F,5,FALSE),0))"
```

It could be worth that you give also a look at .FormulaR1C1 property which might be more explicit from VBA.  If you don't use FormulaR1C1 syntax, pay attention to Absolute/relative address.

```
mySheet.Range("X2").Formula = "=INT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A:$A,[sheet.xls]Sheet1!$B:$F,5,FALSE),0))"
```

If you don't know how to do something with VBA, use the Macro Recorder. Its output is crappy and always needs to be cleaned up, but at leat you get an answer in 5 secs and it's an easy learning tool.

Eventually, enter the formula manually in a cell - say in X2 - then from the Immediate window, you type `Print range("x2").Formula` (or `formulaR1C1`) to see the exact formula to put in your code.

Comment: I tried with below code but i am receiving below error : Error #438 Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I forgot the equal sign at the beginning of the formula. Fixed in the answer

Comment: this is the code which i tried.                                                                                                                    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Applicaiton")                                                                  Set xlbook1 = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(Sheet1.XLS).Sheets("Volume")                      Set xlbook2 = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(Shee2.XLS).Sheets(1)

Comment: Set xlsht1 = xlbook1.Activesheet                                                                                      Set xlsht2=xlbook2.Acitvesheet                                                                                                             xlsht1.Range("J5").Formula= "=(INT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A:$A,xlbook2!$B:$F,5,FALSE),0))"                                          xlbook1.Save                                                                                                                         xlbook1.Close

Comment: I need to do the vlookup dynamically without entering any manual inputs.